# global methods do not support return type of wrapperclass

Tags: apex, rest-api, wrapper-class, type, global

i am getting of error

> global methods do not support return type of ContractResponseWrapper

line is  `global static ContractResponseWrapper postMethod()`
i think i could'nt able to send wrapper class as return type

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ContractAPI/*')
global class MaintenanceContracts {
   @HttpPost
   global static ContractResponseWrapper postMethod() {
      String requestBody = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();    
      MaintenanceContracts mcREST = new MaintenanceContracts();
      return mcREST.createMaintenanceContracts(requestBody);
   }
    
   private ContractResponseWrapper createMaintenanceContracts(String requestBody) {
      ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = maintainanceType(null, requestBody);
      ContractResponseWrapper contractResponse = new ContractResponseWrapper();
      if (responseWrapper.data != null ) {
         contractResponse = (ContractResponseWrapper) Json.deserialize(
           responseWrapper.data,
           ContractResponseWrapper.class
         );
      }
      return contractResponse;
    }
    
    public ResponseWrapper maintainanceType(Id logId, String wrRequestBody) {
      contractsRestWrapper contractRequest = new contractsRestWrapper(); 
      ContractResponseWrapper response  = new ContractResponseWrapper();  
      ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper(null, false, null);
      //SavePoint warrantyRegSavePoint = Database.setSavePoint();
      LogServiceWrapper objLogSerWrp = new LogServiceWrapper();
      Configuration_Setting__mdt logRecordValue = [
        SELECT id, Configuration_Value__c
        FROM Configuration_Setting__mdt
        WHERE isActive__c = true AND MasterLabel = 'maintancecontractLog'
      ];
      //try {
        if (logId != null) {
          LogService.updateLogStatus(logId, 'In Progress');
        }
      //}
        responseWrapper = MaintanceContractCalculation.Calculation(wrRequestBody);

        return responseWrapper;
   }
    //
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class MaintanceContractCalculation {
    public static  responseWrapper Calculation(String requestBody) {
        ResponseWrapper responseWrapper =  CalculationMethod(null , requestBody);
      //  ContractResponseWrapper response  =(ContractResponseWrapper) Json.deserialize(responseWrapper.data,ContractResponseWrapper.class);
        return responseWrapper;     
    } 

    public static ResponseWrapper CalculationMethod(Id logId, String requestBody){
        contractsRestWrapper contractRequest = new contractsRestWrapper(); 
        contractRequest = contractsRestWrapper.parse(requestBody);
        ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper(null,false,null);
        list<ContractResponseWrapper.MasterSchedulers> mst = new list<ContractResponseWrapper.MasterSchedulers>();
        ContractResponseWrapper.MasterSchedulers mast  = new ContractResponseWrapper.MasterSchedulers();
           mast.dealerProfit =10;
           mast.dealerTotalProfit=500;
           mast.laborProfit =600;
           mst.add(mast);
        ContractResponseWrapper.MasterSchedulers mastr  = new ContractResponseWrapper.MasterSchedulers();
           mastr.dealerProfit =105;
           mastr.dealerTotalProfit=5005;
           mastr.laborProfit =600;
           mst.add(mastr);    
      ContractResponseWrapper response  = new ContractResponseWrapper();        
         response.status ='success';
         response.message ='sample response';
         response.masterSchedulers =  mst;
          /* string body = JSON.serialize(response);
          
           ContractResponseWrapper  Resp = (ContractResponseWrapper) Json.deserialize(
            body,
            ContractResponseWrapper.class
          ); 
          responseWrapper.data =  JSON.serialize(Resp);*/
          responseWrapper.data =JSON.serialize(response);
          responseWrapper.status = true;
          responseWrapper.errormessage = '';
          return responseWrapper;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend setting on `RestContext.response` field `responseBody` with the return type for the method `void`. It gives you flexibility changing returned data  even in released managed package :)

Comment: I have changed the wrapper class variables and  class  to global and it works

Comment: It worked for me, i've just changed the wrapper class to global and it works.
The variables could still be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly anything in the signature of a global method (return type, parameter types) must either be standard Apex types or must themselves also be global, otherwise the method cannot be exposed across namespaces. Note, however, that you probably don't need to be using the global access modifier anyway. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm), which says:

> We recommend using the global access modifier rarely, if at all. Cross-application dependencies are difficult to maintain